# Progress bar run in android

Tags: android, performance

I want give some specific time period for  progress bar to run in android. How to do that. I'm stuck with this problem.
Pls answer my question.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for CountDownTimer , if you want timer base progress bar.

see demo from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html